# Yii2 custom validation rule not working

Tags: validation, yii2, rules

I'm trying to write some custom validation for a model in yii2, but I can't figure out why the validation always is positive, although my validation function always adds an error. 
for example the rules

```
   public function rules()
{
    return [
       ...
        [['myattribute'], 'myvalidation'],
   ];
}

public function myvalidation($attribute, $params)
{
  $this->addError($attribute, "error");
}
```

the validate() function still returns true. What's the problem?

Comment: Please show the code in the controller where you have used $model->validate().I was using custom validators in my yii2 project and I don't have any problems yet.

Answer (score 0):

In validation rule add skipOnError  => false

```
[
  ['myattribute', 'myvalidation',  'skipOnError' => false],
]
```

Then

```
$model->validate(); // should return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I will recommend you is watch this [lesson on custom roles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2XRCm-x3iQ&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF&index=26) and 
[read docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators) on it. It's not the best video tutorial, but this guy made it work correctly.

In your case :

1.In `[['myattribute'], 'myvalidation'],` remove extra array from here, make your model rules and custom valdation function look like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
       ...
        ['myattribute', 'myvalidation'],
   ];
}

public function myvalidation($attribute, $params)
{
  $this->addError($attribute, "error");
}
```

it's not wrong, but it's used when you have more than one attribute.

2.Then go to your form and put `` to your ActiveForm so it will look like this

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```

I mean, your need to do it in case if you want to validate it without reloading (using ajax).

3.Also add this to your controller's action that is connected to your view

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

This will validate your input in the form via ajax, if it's not ajax, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
['reg_date','validateDate', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false]
```

add this to your rules

```
public function validateDate($attribute,$params,$validator)
    {
        
            $validator->addError($this,$attribute,"Bugungi sana bo'lishi kerak!");
    }
```

check this in your controller side like this

```
if($model->validate()){
echo "validate works";
}
```